# Delete button not working in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trailhead

I am working on Trailhead module "Build the AccountList Component" https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/slds-lightning-components-workshop/steps/slds-lc-4

When I click on Delete button, it is not showing alert(confirmation) message.

Below is the code -
Lightning component-

```
<form class="account-form" onsubmit="{!c.deleteAccount}">
              <input type="hidden" value="{!account.Name}" class="account-name" />
              <!--
                Use a Lightning Base Component
                To display an icon next to the label
               -->
              <lightning:button label="Delete"
                                iconName="utility:delete"
                                iconPosition="left"
                                variant="destructive"
                                />
            </form>
```

Controller.js code

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {      
    // Fetch the account list from the Apex controller   
    helper.getAccountList(component);
  },
  deleteAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Prevent the form from getting submitted
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the value from the field that's in the form
    var accountName = event.target.getElementsByClassName('account-name')[0].value;
    confirm('Delete the ' + accountName + ' account? (don’t worry, this won’t actually work!)');
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean "nothing is happening"? Also, this code is specifically designed *not* to delete records.

Comment: On click of button, it should show an alert.. but it's not

Answer (score 0):

There is slight mistake in the code sample in Trailhead module.
I had to add new attribute type="submit" in lightning button as shown below to make it work-

```
<lightning:button label="Delete"
                                iconName="utility:delete"
                                iconPosition="left"
                                variant="destructive"
                                **type="submit"**
                                />
```